# IntersectionObserver working scrolling down but not scrolling up

Tags: javascript, scroll, intersection-observer

I am using `IntersectionObserver` to highlight the current section's corresponding nav item.
Everything seems to be working fine unless I scroll upwards. When I do that, the section I just left gets `isIntersecting: false` (as it should) but the one I just entered does not get observed.
Creating a new `IntersectionObserver` for scrolling up seems to be redundant and just wrong, but I don't know how to make the code work in both scrolling directions.

Thanks a lot in advance for your precious help!

Here is the JS:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
const config = {
  rootMargin: "0px 0px -51%",
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      intersectionHandler(entry);
    }
  });
}, config);

sections.forEach((section) => {
  observer.observe(section);
});

function intersectionHandler(entry) {
  const id = entry.target.id;
  const currentlyActive = document.querySelector("#nav a.is-selected");
  const shouldBeActive = document.querySelector(
    "#nav a[data-section=" + id + "]"
  );

  if (currentlyActive) {
    currentlyActive.classList.remove("is-selected");
  }
  if (shouldBeActive) {
    shouldBeActive.classList.add("is-selected");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have your bottom margin set to `-51px` so when you "scroll up", the API continually removes 51px from the viewport's bottom before determining the intersection. Then, a presumption, the next `<section>` comes along and a new intersection is calculated - again, `51px` below the bottom. You should use the threshold API feature rather than setting a negative margin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try.

Comment: Just changed to `const config = {rootMargin: "0px", threshold: 0.5,};` and it worked like a charme! Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome. If I put this in an answer will you upvote and accept?

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your bottom margin set to `-51px` so when you "scroll up", the API continually removes 51px from the viewport's bottom before determining the intersection. Then, a presumption, the next `<section>` comes along and a new intersection is calculated - again, `51px` below the bottom. You should use the threshold API feature rather than setting a negative margin.